# Console error meaning?

Tags: javascript

I'm new to programming and can't figure out what is wrong with this code I'm working on. In the developer console I keep getting these error codes.

> `Hw%20multifuncion.html:24` Uncaught `SyntaxError`: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
>   Hw `multifuncion.html`:34 Uncaught `ReferenceError`: compute is not defined

What do these mean? I'm not familiar with the debugger yet so any help would be much appreciated.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-us">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>WindChill</title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    /* Input: Temperature in fahrenheit and windspeed in mph
     * Processing: Calculate windchill and output to user. While useing two funcions, and assign a call and return.
     * Output: The windchill
     */

    function compute() {
      var temperature = document.getElementById("temperature").value;
      var windspeed = document.getElementById("windspeed").value;
      var temp = parseInt(temperature);
      var wind = parseInt(windspeed);
      var result = windChill(temp, wind);
      document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = result;
    }


    function windChill(tempF, speed) {
      var f = 35.74 + 0.6215 * tempF− 35.75 * Math.pow(speed, 0.16) + 0.4275 * Math.pow(tempF, 0.16);
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  Temperature (Fahrenheit)
  <input type="text" id="temperature" size="5">
  <br>Wind speed (MPH)
  <input type="text" id="windspeed" size="5">
  <button type="button" onclick="compute()">WindChill</button>
  <div id="output"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You’ve got a `−` instead of a `-` symbol. Use [JSHint](http://jshint.com/) before asking.

Comment: also you need to `return f;` in `function windChill()`

Comment: Sometimes errors can be cryptic, in your case, they are not. The syntax error is not a minus sign, and as the script errors out, there is no `compute()` function, and once that is fixed, the function needs to return something

Comment: Thank you, Can't believe I didn't see that. @xufox How am I supposed to us JSHint if I have never even heard of JSHint...

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in your `windChill` function: you are using `−` instead of a `-` symbol.

```
function windChill(tempF,speed) {
    var f = 35.74 + 0.6215*tempF - 35.75*Math.pow(speed,0.16) + 0.4275*Math.pow (tempF,0.16);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, its always the little things I don't see that mess up my code so far..

Answer (score 0):

Your `windChill` function has two issues :

- It needs to return a result. As it is now, you assign your computation to `f`, but you don't do anything with it.
- As Darshan points out, it seems your minus `-` symbol is not the right one.

Simply add `return f;` after your variable assignment and correct your minus symbol.